# How to check out all occurances of a filename from GIT repository recursively?

Tags: git-checkout

I have a GIT repository with a build.xml file in each folder and their subfolders. I need only those build.xml files to be checked out in the same directory structure as they are in the repository. The folder structure will be modified over time and so I want the solution to be dynamic.

One option is to checkout the entire repository and then remove all the files other than build.xmls. But I would like to keep it as last option. Is there any better approach or a one-liner for accomplishing the task?

I am okay with the solution even if the checked out skeleton directory sttrucure is not tracked by GIT.

Comment: Do you want this skeleton directory structure to be tracked by Git?

Comment: No @TimBiegeleisen. I am okay with it even if the checked out skeleton  directory structure is not tracked by GIT.

Comment: Are you running Windows or some flavor of Linux?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 15.04 Server class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing for you to do would be to take the following steps:

1) Change directory to the root of your local Git repo (which contains the various `build.xml` files)

2) Do `git pull origin branch` to get your local repo files (including the `build.xml` files) up to date with the remote

3) Then selectively copy the `build.xml` files from the repo to a new location:

```
find . -name 'build.xml' -exec cp --parents \{\} /new_location \;
```

The above `find` command will move the entire directory structure to `/new_location` which in this case is a directory right under root.

Depending on your Linux ambitions, you might be able to create a single script which can automate all of this.

Comment: Can you explain the parameters you're using? Especially the `\{\}` and `\;`

Comment: Please see [this Unix Stack Exchange article](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83593/copy-specific-file-type-keeping-the-folder-structure) for more information.  In any case, I think selectively copying the `build.xml` files from a fresh copy of the repository is the way to go here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TimBiegeleisen.